# recursive function doesn't execute after second call in php

Tags: php, recursion

I am working on an web App which automate project management process . 
I defined a `task_node` class which stands for a task in a project .
`completePath` function complete the project path from current task `$tNode` to the end of the tasks depending on sequence relation .
My problem is that execution stopped after the first call of `completePath`.
here is my code :

```
private function completePath($tNode,$counter)
{
    // getting data from DB works properly 
    echo '<br>counter:'.$counter.' <br>task name:'.$tNode->task_name;
    $helper=new MySQLHelper();
    //getting initial tasks 
    $cond=" t2.source_task_id='$tNode->task_id'
    And t2.relation_type='sequence'
            AND t1.task_id=t2.target_task_id";
    $tables="tasks t1 , tasks_relations t2";
    $nextTask=$helper->getData($tables,'t1.task_id,t1.task_name,t1.task_duration',$cond);
    if(mysql_num_rows($nextTask)!=0)  // stopping condition 
    {
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($nextTask);
        $tNode->nextTask=new Task_Node($row['task_id'],$row['task_name'],$row['task_duration']);
        completePath($tNode->nextTask,++$counter);//  execution stopped here
    }

}
```

any idea ?? thank u

Comment: What result set does your helper return?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
sizeof($nextTask)
```

or

```
count($nextTask)
```

in place of

```
mysql_num_rows($nextTask).
```

Because mysql_num_rows() retrieves the number of rows from a result set.

Comment: sorry, I didn't tell you that my method `$helper->getData()` returns a result set ..!!

Answer (score 0):

From the information you have provided, you should loop the resource result :

```
   if(mysql_num_rows($nextTask)>0)  // stopping condition 
        {
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($nextTask,MYSQL_ASSOC)){ // loop through the result set 
            $tNode->nextTask=new Task_Node($row['task_id'],$row['task_name'],$row['task_duration']);
            completePath($tNode->nextTask,++$counter);//  execution stopped here
           }
        }
```

`mysql_fetch_array` returns an array that corresponds to the fetched row and moves the internal data pointer ahead.

Also note that the mysql_* function are deprecated from php 5.5. Try to use `mysqli` instead.